# How can I fix this error for my Discord bot I'm trying to make?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to create a Discord bot in JavaScript that plays a specified sound for each specific person that joins the voice channel. It is kind of like an intro sound/song thing.

I'm getting this error when I tried to test it out. It outputs this in the terminal when I join the voice channel and the bot doesn't join the voice channel to play the sound.

```
cd "C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot"
node Audio.js
```

Output:

```
On
C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\Audio.js:29
  } else if (newState.channel.members.size = 1) {
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'members')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\Audio.js:29:31)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\VoiceStateUpdate.js:38:14)
    at module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:489:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\javacode\Discord Audio Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

This is my code below. Also, how would I go about doing this so that each user has their own different sound?

```
console.log('On');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
  ]

});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (_oldState, newState) => {
  // Check if the user who joined is the specific user we want
  if (newState.member.id === 'STtheGamer') {
      // Check if the user joined a voice channel
      if (newState.channel) {
          // Join the voice channel and play the specific sound
          newState.channel.join()
              .then(connection => {
                  // Replace 'song.mp3' with the path to the audio file you want to play
                  const dispatcher = connection.play('C:\Users\storr\Music\botsounds\swtheme.mp3');

                  // Leave the voice channel after the sound is played
                  dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
                      newState.channel.leave();
                  });
              })
              .catch(console.error);
      }
  } else if (newState.channel.members.size = 1) {
      if (newState.channel) {
          newState.channel.leave()
              .catch(console.error);
      }
  }

});

client.login('botkey here');
```

Comment: Why are you checking the number of members of the channel *before* checking if the channel exists? You probably want to reverse that condition

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the path to the audio file in your code. The path you have provided is not a valid path, as it contains a backslash () instead of a forward slash (/) between directories. In JavaScript, backslashes in strings need to be escaped with another backslash, so the correct path should be something like this:

```
const dispatcher = connection.play('C:\\Users\\storr\\Music\\botsounds\\swtheme.mp3');
```

Alternatively, you can use forward slash instead of a backslash to separate directories in the path like this:

```
const dispatcher = connection.play('C:/Users/storr/Music/botsounds/swtheme.mp3');
```

And to allow each user to have their own sound, you could create a mapping of user IDs to audio file paths, and then use this mapping to look up the correct audio file for each user:

```
const introSoundUser = {
   'user1ID' : 'audiofile.path',
   'user2ID' : 'audiofile.path'
};
```

Comment: Did you create this answer using ChatGPT?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Hi, I did not. I'm not a fan of it. I've had a similar problem before so I figured I would try to answer :)

Comment: No problem, the content wasn't the issue, it just had such excellent grammar and spelling I was skeptical.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I see that. I like to run my messages through a grammar checker since English isn't my first language.